# How to get the column having cat

Tags: python, pandas

dataset is below

```
id,cost,product,cost_cat,product_cat
1,12,34,100,200
2,13,35,101,201
3,14,36,102,202
4,15,37,103,203
5,16,38,104,204
```

How to get the column `cost_cat,product_cat` or

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df1 = df[['cost_cat','product_cat']]
```

- I need to delete the column name which doesn't having  `cat` and create a new dataframe
- I need to select the column name which having  `cat` and create a new dataframe
- I need to select the first column `df.iloc[:,0]` and the find the column which is having the `cat

Psuedo code which throw indexerror

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('cat'),df.iloc[:,0] ]
```

I got the solution by adding

`df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('cat')| df.columns.str.contains('id')]`

but i need to get the with number like `df.iloc[:,0]`

Comment: `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('cat')]`?

Comment: or even simplier `pd.read_csv(....,usecols=lambda x : re.search('cat',x))`

Comment: @QuangHoang, if i want `id` which is my primary key then how to extract, that is my first column `df['0']`

Comment: @Datanovice  if i want id which is my primary key then how to extract, that is my first column df['0'] ,  df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('cat'),d2.iloc[:,0] ], i am getting indexing error

Comment: set it as your index `df.set_index('id').loc....`